# Libxml_disable_entitiy_loader(false); Still no external entities loaded

Tags: php, xml, libxml2, xxe

I've been trying to mimic the XXE vulnerability on my virtual machine for learning purposes. However, I think I misunderstand something. When I call libxml_disable_external_entities(false); I would think that external entities are now loaded, however, external entities does not seem to load.

When I set the flag LIBXML_NOENT, it does work. But that leaves me with the question, what does libxml_disable_external_entities actually do then? I have set it both to false and true, with the same results.

So I went to the internet with the same question and noticed a CVE report on the ubuntu website (I have tested on ubuntu). The CVE stated that libxml is standard vulnerable to XXE. The fix was to stop loading external entities by default. See: https://usn.ubuntu.com/1904-1/

My test setup:

```
<?php
  $xml= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <!DOCTYPE foo [  
  <!ELEMENT foo ANY >
  <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://www.localhost:8000" >]><foo>&xxe;</foo>';

  libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $document->loadXML($xml); 
?>
```

I expected my webserver to receive a call, but it did not. The PHP handler gives me no output. So my question: what does libxml_disable_entity_loader actually do?

PS: Could not find anything in libxml code either. Could find the fix to stop loading external entities unless otherwise stated, though.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I have found that it only works with the combination if libxml_disable_entitiy_loader(false); and the LIBXML_NOENT flag set in the 'loadXML' method.

EDIT:
The method does the following (in PHP code):

```
PHP_LIBXML_API zend_bool php_libxml_disable_entity_loader(zend_bool disable) /* {{{ */
{
    zend_bool old = LIBXML(entity_loader_disabled);

    LIBXML(entity_loader_disabled) = disable;
    return old;
}
```

However, searching for entity_loader_disabled yields no results in libxml code.

Comment: Maybe this test case from PHP source code will shed some light on how it's expected to work: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/libxml/tests/libxml_disable_entity_loader.phpt

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the link. I'm afraid I don't quite get it yet. Apparently not getting external entities is the default. Why is the method even there then? What does it do (as LIBXML_NOENT flag will get the external entities only once)